# RCP Application with Progress View in eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to disable the stop button of `IProgressMonitor` in progress view of an RCP application.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. What 'progress view'? Is this something you have written?

Comment: I am working one eclipse rcp application , in which i added one progress view ,which is used to show job progress with iprogress monitor. i just want to hide/disable stop(red button) of iprogress monitor .

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing your own extension of [`org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FProgressMonitorDialog.html) instead, which has a method [`setCancelable(boolean)`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FProgressMonitorDialog.html).